# How can I remove things from my shop?

Tags: pocket-clothier

I have accidentally built two Dumpling Stands when I only wanted one.

Problem is, I can't seem to figure out a way to completely remove things, only move them, and I have nowhere to move the second Dumpling Stand to in order to build what I really want.

How can I remove things from my shop? Is this possible? Or am I stuck with my mistakes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you first tap the screen, you get the "install" screen, where you can place new items.  Tapping an item from here will bring up the move menu, which allows you to move things.  It also allows you to remove items, via the remove button in the bottom left.